# How to define constant based on device type (iPad/iphone)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, constants

I am trying to define constants in one of my file in my project.

i know, i can define it like below

```
const CGSize kSize = { 46.f, 44.f };
```

But what i am trying to achieve like this :

```
if device type iPad

const CGSize kSize = { 146.f, 144.f };

else

const CGSize kSize = { 46.f, 44.f };
```

Is it possible to achieve above point ?

Can any one help me how can i achieve this. any help or any guidance will be helpful.

Comment: I solved this kind of problems with a seperate class and static methodes. so you can implement much more case logic in it. But for only one you can use a simple static variable and define it in load of class

Comment: The title is misleading. I changed it to what you actually wanna do

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your app is a universal app then you don't know at compile time what device your app is gonna run on (of course you can run iPhone apps on an iPad, but they retain their iPhone dimensions). You need a runtime check to determine which size is appropriate.

```
UIUserInterfaceIdiom idiom = UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM();

if (idiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    // iPad
} else if (idiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    // iPhone
}
```

Comment: You could wrap that in methods isIPad / isIPhone for nicer looking code

Answer (score 4):

Use this as:

```
#define IS_IPAD (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)

if (IS_IPAD) {
 const CGSize kSize = { 146, 144 };
} else {
  const CGSize kSize = { 46, 44 };
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Its just an example. You can make it global as per your need.

Answer (score 2):

```
const CGSize kSize;

if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
  kSize = { 146, 144 };
} else {
  kSize = { 46, 44 };
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Define it globally.

```
#define IS_IPAD (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)    
if(IS_IPAD)
    const CGSize kSize = { 146.f, 144.f };
else
    const CGSize kSize = { 46.f, 44.f };
```

check in every class like

```
if(IS_IPAD)
 // kSize........for iPad
else
 //---- else part --------
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it like this:

```
#define isIpad (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
#define kSizeIpad CGSizeMake(146.f, 44.f)
#define kSizeIPhone CGSizeMake(46.f, 44.f)
```

Now you can check if the code is running on an iPhone or iPad:

```
if (isIpad) {
    CGSize sizeIpad = kSizeIpad;
} else {
    CGSize sizeIphone = kSizeIPhone;
}
```

My suggestion is to put one `.h` file (e.g. `KConstand.h`) in the project and define all your constant variables there.

For example:

```
#ifndef Myproject_kConstant_h
#define Myproject_kConstant_h

#define isiPhone5 (CGRectGetHeight([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds) == 568) ? YES : NO
#define isiPhone (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == 0)

#define kSizeIpad CGSizeMake(146, 44)
#define kSizeIPhone CGSizeMake(46, 44)

#endif
```